# Symfony special characters in Twig file causing error

Tags: symfony, frameworks, symfony1, twig

For pages with lots of text and html tags, I quickly get a parsing error from Twig due to unexpected special characters. Has anybody else ran into this problem?

`Unexpected character "!" in ... at line 76`

I am trying to fix this problem by pasting the static information in a new page and then including it using `include`.

My question is, where should I place a static HTML file so it can be included in a Twig file using `{% include 'content.html' %}`? Currently the included file is in the `FooBundle/Resources/views/Default` directory.

What is a good practice for overcoming this problem, and if include is the answer, where should the file be located to be included in a twig?

Note:

When I try to link to it using `{% include 'content.html' %}` I get the following Symfony error:

`Unable to find template "content.html" in ... at line 31` (broken link)

Comment: Try to specify full path? 'FooBundle:Default:content.hmtl'

Comment: Could you show some lines of code around the `!`? I would be interested in what exactly happened there. Other than that @Ivan0x32 solution should work.

Comment: @ivan0x32 thanks for the reply. This did not work. I am getting the following error: `Unable to find template ` because I'm guessing its looking for a Twig template (with a `.html.twig` extension). When I add the Twig extension, I am getting the initial error of Unexpected `!` character.

Comment: @byf-ferdy the `code` is simply English paragraphs of information. It includes `'` some characters and `!` characters naturally. For testing, once I remove all the `!` characters, I get the same error but this time complaining about `Unexpected ' character`.

Comment: I think you might have a syntax error somewhere else in your code. please give us some code.

Comment: No syntax errors. See solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, drawing from various different posts. I ended up putting the raw html in a new file (which isn't required) and included it as follows:

`{% include 'FooBundle:Default:content.html.twig' %}`

Then inside my `content.html.twig` I surrounded my raw HTML code with `raw` Twig tags:

```
{% raw %}

// RAW HTML CODE HERE

{% endraw %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include like this

```
{% include 'YourProjectNameFooBundle:Default/content.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: This did not work, throwing an error that it is unable to find template. In addition, I am getting the initial error of `Unexpected character !`. This does not help me import raw **html** like I need, just another template.